# Retrieving a jade template without inherited parts with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, pug

I have a database of Texts that are rendered as single pages, as most of them require a different layout and (most importantly) i18n.

the structure is:

```
baseLayout.jade
  DBtemplate.jade
    actualText.jade
```

(i have to make each text in a single jade file, so i can translate them):

```
extends ../DBtemplate
    block tipContent
        - var path = "[html]text.cat1.subcat2."
        h1(data-i18n=path + "0")
        .tipsFrame
            .tipsText
                p(data-i18n=path + "1")
                p(data-i18n=path + "2")
                p(data-i18n=path + "3")
                p(data-i18n=path + "4")
                // ...
```

all files are glued together via extends/block

no problems here. the normal overview works, i can display any single text fine.

now i want to render those in another page (as optional hint-section).

obviously, i will have to reload them with ajax, that's probably not going to be a problem. the problem is:

## how can i load **only** the text itself (`actualText.jade`), without all the layout from the extends?

is this possible?
maybe with includes? but then again, includes seem to be static...?

thanks

Comment: You will have to split your actualtext.jade into two templates... one with the actual content, another with all the layout extends et al and include the actual in the other. In your ajax call, you can retrieve only the actual text and display it as a hint or whatever way you want to. Hope this helps